# How to close magnificPopup popup

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup in my project. I am opening pop up on mouseover and loading ajax content.

**Code:**

```
$('.link-popup').mouseover(function(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        type: 'ajax',
        removalDelay: 300,
        items: {
            src: 'ajax/popup.html' 
        }
   })
});
```

I have a close link in the popup.html and want to close the pop up on that link click. How can I do this?
Below is my close link in HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="link-close">X</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attach the event to the document object and reference the a tag class selector like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link-close', function(evt){

  $.magnificPopup.close();

});
```